# list 2 columns even using ngFor Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I had some problems which I need to iterate data from object response into  2 `columns`, and data are dynamic, which are odd and even number, let says I got 5 list of data to display using 2 `columns`, it will became 3 on left and other 2 on right, so it will became problem for me since are the columns are not same in left and right, is there are any **CSS** trick to apply,to make `columns` even.this is what i had tried:

**html file**

```
<ul class="ul1">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let p of (myData?.paymentChannels| slice:0:2)">
  <li 
  [style.background]="getBackgroundColor(p.status)"
   class="li1">
  <span>{{p.name}}</span>
  <br>
  <span>{{p.status}}</span>
  </li>
  </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let p of (myData?.paymentChannels| slice:2:5)">
  <li 
  [style.background]="getBackgroundColor(p.status)"
   class="li1">
  <span>{{p.name}}</span>
  <br>
  <span>{{p.status}}</span>
  </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

and this is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkg3cq?file=src/assets/test.json) demo, I could use some suggestion and solution to solve mine,

**expected output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional `<li>` id no. of items in the list is odd:

Like this:

```
<li  class="li1" *ngIf="myData?.paymentChannels.length % 2 !=0"></li>
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="ul1">
    <li [style.background]="getBackgroundColor(p.status)" class="li1" *ngFor="let p of myData?.paymentChannels">
        <span>{{p.name}}</span>
      <br>
      <span>{{p.status}}</span>
    </li>
    <li  class="li1" *ngIf="myData?.paymentChannels?.length % 2 !=0"></li>
</ul>
```

In class `li1` add min-height:

```
.li1 {
    min-height: 40px
 }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3qufcp?embed=1&file=src/app/payment/payment.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result with CSS, add border to `ul1` and add `padding:0px` to avoid default `ul` indentation

```
.ul1 {
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 0;
border: 1px solid blue;
padding: 0px;
}
```

working code for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xoqy9r?file=src/app/payment/payment.component.css